# Cannot get the Future boolean value in the conditional statement

Tags: android, flutter, dart

cannot get the future value to true or false inside the conditional statement.

**Future Function Code Here (returns true)**

```
Future<bool> authorizeAccess(context) async {
    bool iadmin;
    await firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get().then((doc) {
      if (doc.data()['role'] == 'admin') {
        print('Authorized!!');
        iadmin = true;
      } else {
        print("Not Authorized");
        iadmin = false;
      }
    });
    print(iadmin);
    return iadmin;
  }
```

Now i am trying to get the value and return "true" or "false" by using the following function
**(returns null)**

```
bool runMyValue() {
authorizeAccess(context).then((value) {
 isadmin = value;
});
print(isadmin);
return isadmin;
}
```

I want to get true value so that i can able to login to admin page if I am admin or else login to delivery boy page

**Full Code Here**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:boolean/boolean.dart';
//Pages
import 'package:DavagenieRunnerApp/Delivery%20Boy/Screen/test.dart';
import 'package:DavagenieRunnerApp/Services/Login.dart';
//Firebase Packages
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
bool isadmin;

class UserManagement {
  Widget handleAuth() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      //Initialize FireBase
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
            ),
          );
        }
        //if connection active show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                User user = snapshot.data;

                bool runMyValue() {
                  authorizeAccess(context).then((value) {
                    isadmin = value;
                  });
                  print(isadmin);
                  return isadmin;
                }

                if (user != null) {
                  if (runMyValue() == true) {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushReplacementNamed('/adminHomepage');
                    });
                  } else {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushReplacementNamed('/deliveryHomepage');
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
                  });
                }
              }
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text("Checking Authentication"),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
        return LoginScreen();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> authorizeAccess(context) async {
    bool iadmin;
    await firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get().then((doc) {
      if (doc.data()['role'] == 'admin') {
        print('Authorized!!');
        iadmin = true;
      } else {
        print("Not Authorized");
        iadmin = false;
      }
    });
    print(iadmin);
    return iadmin;
  }

  signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can only use one await or .then(). They both do the same thing but await is much better since you won't get stuck in callback hell <- popular mistake in nodejs . Try using this instead of having await and .then() in the end: final doc = await firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

Comment: then() you have no control of behavior timing.
Use await for better control

Comment: @Uni I still getting null value if i try to return value in the conditional statement

Comment: I'm not sure why you are still getting null. Double check if the values in your database is correct and print all the data being returned by firestore.